# How to expose a map of pointers as a map of const pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, dictionary, constants

I have a class with an std::map of pointers as a member. Now, I'd like to expose that member in a read only fashion: modification is not allowed for neither the map, nor the objects pointed to. Internally I need those pointers to be non-const, and I want to expose them as const.

I do have a solution that compiles at least, but I'd like to know if there's any hidden problems I'll run into with this.

```
class A
{
public:
  const std::map<int, const float*>& GetMap() const { return *(reinterpret_cast< const std::map<int, const float*>* >( &m_Map)); }

private:
  std::map<int, float*> m_Map;
};
```

There's a possible problem I can think of: if the internal layout of std::map is different for maps of pointers and maps of const pointers, then this will cause ugly bugs. But I cannot think of any sane reason why that would be the case. Anybody has any idea?

To clarify: I am aware that this is a hack, and there are safer solutions (like separate accessor functions). I am just wondering if this would break right away because of some piece of information I'm missing.

Comment: The C-style rules for automatic downcasting to `const` have not kept up well with modern C++ programming, unfortunately.

Comment: You could use a map of pointer-like objects (a.k.a. 'smart pointers') that propagate constness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is of course undefined (EDIT: it looks like it's actually only unspecified) behavior because the two maps are (from the language point of view) totally unrelated types. It may appear to work now but sometime it's going to break and cause a ton of headaches.

Did you consider that instead of exposing an implementation detail (that you're using map internally) you could provide `const_iterator`s and a `find` method for your class's public interface instead?

EDIT:
See 5.2.10/7:

> A pointer to an object can be
>   explicitly converted to a pointer to
>   an object of different type. 65) Except
>   that converting an rvalue of type
>   “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer
>   to T2” (where T1 and T2 are object
>   types and where the alignment
>   requirements of T2 are no stricter
>   than those of T1) and back to its
>   original type yields the original
>   pointer value, the result of such a
>   pointer conversion is unspecified.

From that quote we conclude that casting from the map with non-const value type to the map with const value type has unspecified behavior. Further, actually dereferencing the converted pointer would probably violate the strict aliasing rules and result in undefined behavior.

Comment: +1, hiding the implementation is the best way, even if it seems like more work.

Comment: Generally speaking you're right, but... I don't see any reason for the const pointer and non-const pointer versions of the container to be any different. Could you tell me a valid reason for that to be the case?

Comment: Or in general, you could look at the Sorted Associative Container interface, cross out anything that requires the container to be non-const, and decide how much of the remainder you want to implement. Then write a class that adapts a map of non-const pointers and implements everything you decided.

Comment: @Zed The standard says they can be different, so I wouldn't want to speculate on what a compiler might do given that leeway.

Comment: @Mark B Really? I don't think the standard mentions that... (Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. :-) ) It's more like a given possibility because it's a template class. I just don't see any reason for it.

Comment: @Zed Since the types are unrelated there are problems regarding e.g. aliasing.

Comment: To Mark B's edit: Indeed you're right sir, I surrender before your arguments. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could hold it as a map<int, const float *> and const_cast internally when you need to. This is ugly but legal (as long as you know that all the values pointed to really aren't const).

At least it doesn't involve Undefined Behaviour which I'm pretty certain your solution does. Although as you say it will probably work most of the time on most platforms.

Answer (score 0):

That reinterpret_cast generates a reference with unspecified behavior. Don't do that! Use const_iterators.

```
class A {
public:
  typedef std::map<int, float*> MapType;
  typedef MapType::const_iterator const_iterator;

  const_iterator begin () const { return m_Map.begin(); }

  const_iterator end () const { return m_Map.end(); }

private:
  std::map<int, float*> m_Map;
};


void some_function () {
  A my_map;

  // Code to build the map elided

  for (A::const_iterator iter = my_map.begin(); iter < my_map.end(); ++iter) {
    do_something_with_but_not_to (*iter);
  }
```

Note that you can also export things such as find that return a const_iterator.

Comment: It's not making a copy, and with the const_iterators I can still modify the pointed objects.

Comment: Ah yes, You aren't making a copy. You are making a reference with unspecified behavior. Regarding modifying the pointed-to objects: You can't do that without using a C-style cast or a const_cast. Many projects make const_casts verboten (you need a waiver). Most projects make C-style casts and reinterpret_cast utterly verboten (waiver granted when the project manager or project dies, whichever is later).

Answer (score 0):

One good reason why it might cause trouble: Even if binary implementation is usually the same (and it usually is, but who knows), then types are still different. Some containers might use some static (or TLS now in C++11) fields (eg. for optimizations/debugging purposes), and those must be different for different types.

Imagine, that such a field would be a (null-initialized) pointer, that is given some significant value in constructor (if not assigned already). As long as no object of this type are constructed it's safe to assume that nobody will deference it, and after first constructor call, it's OK to deference it without checking if it's non-null. Your code can produce container that was never constructed, but it's methods deference internal pointer, leading to difficult to track segfault.